# importing files in php using require() not working

Tags: php, import, global-variables

i tried the following code to import two files

```
<?php echo "php";
    require('../globalvasr.php') or die("error");
    require('../newcosn.php') or die("error2");
    $config = new GlobalConfigs();
?>
```

It does not shows error and it just simply displays a blank page.Also i am unable to use the variable defined in those two files.
Like `$config->DBNAME`.
I dont know whats wrong in this.
Please help me find it.

Thank you.

Comment: Check the spelling `globalvars.php` makes more sense, etc. The `../` means the files are one directory up from the script called.

Comment: spelling were correct.I gave it intentionally.Even when i use 'require('globalvasr.php') or die("error");' same result.

Comment: Both files were in same directory only

Comment: Same directory is `./` not `../`

Answer (score 1):

`require`, in contrast to `include`, automatically dies and does not have a return value.
This means the `or die()` is bad. Better:

```
<?php echo "php";
    require('./globalvasr.php');
    require('./newcosn.php');
    $config = new GlobalConfigs();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Require generates a fatal error when require fails, causing the script execution to stop immediatly.

As you seem to be running in a web env, your output (all echo or print statements) is buffered until the end of the script.

So here the require fails, causing a fatal error (that should be available in the error log) before the output buffer is emptied, preventing your first "echo" to be sent to the browser. that's why you get a blank page.

Try replacing the require with an include, you will get a warning instead of the fatal error.

Comment: tried using include it works but unable calling the constructor GlobalConfigs() causes the problem.

Comment: In which file is your GlobalConfigs class defined ? Is the file included ?

Answer (score 0):

if you have blank page, set `error_reporting: E_ALL` and `Display_errors: On` in `php.ini` or put on start of your script these lines

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('Display_errors','On');
```

then you will see errors

Comment: This doesn't work because it should be a lowercase 'd' in `ini_set('display_errors', 'On')`